# Quarkus - Disable kafka connection with smallrye-kafka for dev mode

Tags: quarkus

In dev mode there are scenarios where I want to disable connection to kafka because I want to validate other interfaces of my app and don't want to start a local kafka. so I disable the topics with the this configuration:

```
mp.messaging.connector.smallrye-kafka.health-enabled=false
mp.messaging.incoming.<topic>.health-enabled=false
mp.messaging.incoming.<topic>.health-readiness-enabled=false
```

However the application won't start if the bootstrap urls are not resolved

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:101)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:60)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:56)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:707)
```

or with this error if cannot connect.

```
2024-03-20T15:50:03.861 WARN  traceId=, parentId=, spanId= [or.ap.ka.cl.NetworkClient] (smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-0) [Consumer clientId=kafka-consumer-ot, groupId=sigo-nossis-adapter] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2024-03-20T15:50:05.281 WARN  traceId=, parentId=, spanId= [or.ap.ka.cl.NetworkClient] (smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-1) [Consumer clientId=kafka-consumer-ttk, groupId=sigo-nossis-adapter] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

Is there a way to start locally without this errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a different config profile on which you disable certain channels and beans using them. Note that your application still needs to be complete in terms of CDI beans and messaging channels.

Here is a short guide on how to achieve this: https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka#conditionally-configure-channels

For example,
with config `%my-profile.mp.messaging.[incoming|outgoing].<channel>.enabled=false`
you can disable a channel on `my-profile`.
And by annotating your beans with `@UnlessBuildProfile("my-profile")` you can remove them from the application.

Lastly you can run the Quarkus app with the option `-Dquarkus.profile=my-profile` to activate a profile.